# Python function calling another function and arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that I have a function which takes 10 arguments and another functions which takes 11 arguments and the second one is calling the first one. My code:

```
def func10(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10):
    return a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10

def func11(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11):
    return a11 + func10(a1=a1, a2=a2, a3=a3, a4=a4, a5=a5, a6=a6, a7=a7, a8=a8, a9=a9, a10=a10)
```

Is it possible to write it nicer, i.e. without writing `a1=a1, a2=a2, ...`?

**EDIT**
Maybe to be more precise: in the function `func11` the arguments are `a1, a2, ... a11`. Ten of these arguments are also passed to `func10` function with exactly the same names. I would like to make this works:

```
def func11(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11):
    return a11 + func10(arguments)

func11(a1=a1, a11=11, a2=a2, a3=a3, a4=a4, a5=a5, a6=a6, a7=a7, a8=a8, a9=a9, a10=10)
```

so that I can change the order of arguments when calling `func11` but the proper arguments (i.e. a1 - a10) should be passed to `func10` inside `func11` in a simple way instead of writing again `a1=a1` .... How can I do that? And I don't want to do summation in my function, this is just an example!

Comment: Your parameters correspond to the position, so you only need to use the form of position parameters: `func10(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10)`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 0):

#### You don’t need the equals sign and the extra

You can just call it like this:

```py
def func11(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11):
    return a11 + func10(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10)
```

As far as I know you only need argname=object when you use kwargs or a single kwarg.

##### **Update:** to match the questions update.

You can define function 11 with kwargs and then pass them on.

```py
def func11(**kwargs):
   return kwargs['a11'] + func10(kwargs['a1'],kwargs['a2'], etc.)
#this let’s you change the position how you want ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly state `a1=a1` for every argument `func10(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10)` will do the same although you most likely should consider using `*args` or `**kwargs` for something like this.
Example:

```
def func10(*args):
    total = 0
    for num in args:
        total += num
    return num
```

Edit: To clarify this would only work if you intended on doing something similar with each argument

Check @MatsLindh answer I think its the best for your scenario if your doing anything more advanced than the solution I suggested (which is likely)

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
The following takes advantage of un-packing in function 11.

Receive 10 arguments in func10 pass the 10 arguments to func11 
in a different order plus one additional argument.

"""

def func10(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10):
    print('func10 original order  ',[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10] )
    a11 = 5
    # Pass original arguments to func11 in different order
    for_func11 = [a3, a2, a1, a4, a6, a5, a7, a8, a11, a10,a9]
    func11(*for_func11)
       
    return a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10

def func11(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11):
    print('func11 parameter values',list((b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11)))
    return b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11


func10(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
```

output

```
func10 original order   [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
func11 parameter values [3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9, 5, 11, 10]
```

Comment: You got the amount of arguments the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Define your functions to instead take a list of arguments for a1-a10 then specify a11 as a keyword argument:

```py
def func10(*args):
    return sum(args)

def func11(*args, **kwargs):
    return kwargs['a11'] + func10(*args)

print(func11(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, a11=11))
# Outputs 66
```

Note: This assume `a11` exists.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to pass arguments to a function. Here's some examples on how you could use them:

## using `args` only

```py
def func10(*args):
    return sum(args)

def func11(*args):
    return args[-1] + func10(*args[:-1])

the_args = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,42]
print(func11(*the_args))
```

## using `kwargs` and ignoring `a11`

```py
def func10(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, **ignored_kwargs):
    return a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10

def func11(**kwargs):
    return kwargs['a11'] + func10(**kwargs)

the_kwargs = dict(a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4, a5=5, a6=6, a7=7, a8=8, a9=9, a10=10, a11=42)
print(func11(**the_kwargs))
```

## using `kwargs` values assuming order is correct as `args`

```py
def func10(*args):
    return sum(args[:-1])

def func11(**kwargs):
    return kwargs['a11'] + func10(*kwargs.values())

the_kwargs = dict(a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4, a5=5, a6=6, a7=7, a8=8, a9=9, a10=10, a11=42)
print(func11(**the_kwargs))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def func10(data):
    return sum(data)
    
    
def func11(data):
    return data[10] + func10(data[:10:])
    
    
def main():
    a1 = 1
    a2 = 2
    a3 = 3
    a4 = 4
    a5 = 5
    a6 = 6
    a7 = 7
    a8 = 8
    a9 = 9
    a10 = 10
    a11 = 11
    print(func11([a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11]))

main()
```

Based on your edit you can change the order of the arguments inside the list for the initial func11 call.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a bit of trickery by using `locals()` as the first statement inside your function, effectively capturing all the arguments given to the function and their values. You can then use `**kwargs` to pass these on to the previous function - but you need to remove `a11` first, since `func10` doesn't know anything about it.

```py
def func10(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10):
    return a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10


def func11(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11):
    given_args = locals()
    del given_args['a11']
    
    return func10(**given_args) + a11
    
    
print(func10(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
print(func11(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
```

Output:

```
55
66
```

However, if this is something you see yourself having to do a lot, you might want to define `a1`, `a2` etc. as properties of a Pydantic model instead, and then let each step populate another value in that model.

Comment: There really isn't a good reason to use `locals()` here.

Comment: @ndc85430 That really depends on the _actual_ use case of OP. If you want to dynamically capture everything given to the function to pass it on to another function, without specifying each argument (which seems to be what OP is asking about), then that's at least one way to do it. If the goal is to be explicit, OP has already posted the answer to that in the question. Feel free to argue why you feel that `locals()` isn't a good solution for that interpretation.